# Questions about Link2SD and SD card partitioning

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, samsung, partitions, link2sd

I have a Samsung S3 mini, no support for SD cards so i had to root it, and install Link2SD, spent the last 3 days hacking my phone making it better.

But i have questions, in all the tutorials everywhere on the web, they say ([I refer to this blog](http://www.noypigeeks.com/android/tutorial-a-guide-to-link2sd/) but there are many other blog posts and xda posts and youtube videos that say the same)

- if you have stock rom, use ext 2? (isn't ext 4 supported?)
- partition your SD card, the max for your apps is 2 GB (I have 8 GB,why can't I partition it like 6 GB for apps, and 2 GB Fat32 for music, OR all of it ext2 or 4 and add whatever to it?)
- You install link2SD first time, it asks for root permission, it asks what partition type you're using (ext 2, ext 4, whatever) and it asks to reboot the device, that's fine. But when you install it second or third time, it only asks for root permission, it doesn't reboot the device nor what partition type you're using. Why? maybe I changed (and i did change many times) the partition type, it doesn't ask, so doesn't detect it.
- Once linked, what is the location of the apps? (`data/app` is empty, though i haven't move everything)

Sorry for asking too many question at once, but link2sd is not a big deal, it doesn't deserve asking many questions about it so i tried to put everything in 1 question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, stock rom does not support other file systems but EXT2 for the second partition. So create an EXT2 partition.

the location of the apps, once linked with link2sd will be from the root of the sytem:
\ (which is root)
sd-ext
and there you will find some directories or app-files, depending on your link2sd settings.

About the question for mounting / rebooting: I cannot answer that because I do not know.

about the size of thee partition: when you connect your phone to your computer, and have minitool partition wizard installed, you should be able to create the partitions like you want it and with the size you want.

But to be honest: 6gb for apps is an awfully lot... I think the tutorial just points out that you probably never will exceed the 2 gb that is mentioned and you can use the other 6gb for normal storage (which also can be read by windows when you connect your phone to your computer)

I hope I answered your questions...

Comment: kinda late but hey i'm buying a new sd card now so this will help me partition my new sd card